# what wrong with my sqlite query ?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using sqlite over android and i keep getting the same exceotion and i can't understand why

The table is

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STUDENTS_TABLE
                            + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
                            + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + GROUP + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                            + CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (STUDENT_NAME, GROUP));";
```

and the query that i take is ( try to get all student that are in specific group )

```
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + STUDENTS_TABLE + " WHERE group + "=" + groupName;
```

The exception is

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM students WHERE group=class1

#

Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM students WHERE group=class1)

#

and i can't see anything wrong in my query

Comment: It looks like you have a '+' where it shouldn't be  " WHERE group + "=" should be " WHERE group =" And or 'group' might need to be 'GROUP'

Comment: what ? i can't understand it

Comment: Group is also a keyword in SQL. You should probably quote it like "group" in your query (you'll probably have to escape the quotes).

Comment: You will probably bet much better off by not using **`GROUP`** (or any keyword) as a column name. So I'd suggest changing the definition of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put quote so sqlite will detect it as a string. Try this :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `" + STUDENTS_TABLE + "` WHERE `group` + "='" + groupName +"'";
```

Comment: The string literal needs single quotes

Comment: Although the syntax is technically incorrect, it might still work in some cases given that if a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string literal instead of an identifier.  It might give mysterious results if there is a valid identifier that matches the literal.

Comment: The backquotes suffer from the same problem as the double-quotes.  To ensure correct operation, you should use single-quote (e.g. apostrophe ' ), otherwise you can have strange errors if there is a valid identifier which matches the literal.